# How to save a universal value in a Salesforce Instance

Tags: custom-object, class, static-resources

I need to save a value in a Salesforce Instance which should be universally accessible (In VisualForce Pages, Apex Classes). An example would be to save the account ID to link all contacts (from the apex code), username/password combination and so on. Out of the three methods listed below which one is the best?

1. Static Resourcce
2. Static Class
3. Custom object with a single record (Get the value be querying the field)

Answer (score 6):

None of them.

A custom setting is what you are looking for. They are available to Apex code, Visualforce, and Formulas. Take a look at the docs and examples

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm